# how to map and display array data in table form in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I have data saved in SQL in the form below :
[image]Once I retrieve the data in array format in react such as :

`const tbldata = [[cat,dog,bird,cow],[victoria,vancouver,calgary,montreal],[apple,mango,bananas,grapes],[car,plane,truck,train]];`

`const headers = [A,B,C,D];`

How do I display the data in table form in React.js? Like this below?

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cat | dog | bird | cow |
| victoria | vancouver | calgary | montreal |
| apple | mango | bananas | grapes |
| car | plane | truck | train |

I tried using material table because I'm not sure how to use the other table. This is what I tried :

```html
<MaterialTable
    columns = headers     
    data = tbldata
\>
```

Which is not what I'm looking for. I don't know how to map the array data in a table format.

Comment: `<MaterialTable columns=headers data=tblData />` ?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://material-table.com/#/docs/get-started) or any [tutorials](https://blog.logrocket.com/material-table-react-tutorial-with-examples/)?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you.

```
 class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
            <MaterialTable
              columns={[
                { title: 'A', field: 'A' },
                { title: 'B', field: 'B' },
                { title: 'C', field: 'B' },
                { title: 'D', field: 'D' }
              ]}
              data={tbldata.map((item)=> ({A: item[0], B: item[1], C: item[2]}))}
              title="Title"
            />
        )
      }
    }
```